# attaching to a div with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Pretty new to Jquery/Ajax/Js. How would i go about binding/delegating the following code to either a container div or the document itself so that when i reload a div(that uses the code) with jquery the code does not break like it currently does in a document.ready();

```
$.each($(".product-comment"), function (key, value) {

    var showmoreHtml = $(this).html();
    var showlessHtml = showmoreHtml.substr(0, 400);
    if (showmoreHtml.length > 400) {
        $(this).html(showlessHtml).append("<a href='' class='product-comment-more'> (...Show More)</a>");
    } else {
        $(this).html(showmoreHtml);
    }
    $(this).on("click", ".product-comment-more", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent(".product-comment").html(showmoreHtml).append("<a href='' class='sight-comment-less'> (Show less)</a>");
    });
    $(this).on("click", ".product-comment-less", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent(".product-comment").html(showmoreHtml.substr(0, 400)).append("<a href='' class='product-comment-more'> (...Show More)</a>")
    });
});
```

Comment: What is the event that should trigger that each loop? I assume `.product-comment` is a **static** container that gets "reloaded" using Ajax... Am I right?

Comment: Its currently in the document.ready() but obviously this gets nulified when a div is reloaded so i need to bind/delegate the above code out of the document ready so it works after a reload of the div that the product-comment is in.

Answer (score 0):

First thing is to place that *more/less* function to add link in a named function... So you can run it from anywhere in the code. Have all the logic there.

Then, the click handlers (on *more* and *less*) can be defined out of that loop. There is no use to define them more than once, since they are delegated. And make it run the loop in the named function passing a true/false argument to the function.

Finally... On [*ajaxComplete*](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/), run that function again.

So all *more/less* fixes will be done on load, click and ajaxComplete.

```
function moreLess(more){
  $.each($(".product-comment"), function (key, value) {

      // Remove any more/less link (if any)
      $(this).find("[class^='product-comment-']").remove();

      // Get the remaining HTML
      var HTML = $(this).html();

      // Decide about the more or less link. If "more" is false,
      if (HTML.length > 400 && more) {
        $(this).html(HTML).append("<a href='' class='product-comment-more'> (Show less)</a>");
      }
      if (HTML.length > 400 && !more) {
        $(this).html(HTML.substr(0, 400)).append("<a href='' class='product-comment-more'> (...Show More)</a>");
      }
      if (HTML.length <= 400) {
        $(this).html(HTML);
      }
  });
}

// On page load execution
moreLess(false);

// On ajax complete execution
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function(){
  moreLess(false);
});

// Click handler for more.
$(".product-comment").on("click", ".product-comment-more", function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  moreLess(true)
});

// Click handler for less.
$(".product-comment").on("click", ".product-comment-less", function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  moreLess(false)
});
```

Disclaimer: written quickly and untested... But I'm confidant it will work fine. Feel free to ask questions. ;)